# SQL Selecting finished orders with multiple operations

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, jet

I have a list of orders with suboperations. How can I create a list of finished orders? Finished order must have finished all suboperations.

Table "orders":

```
order_no | suboperation | finished
1        | preparing    | 01/01/2009
1        | scrubbing    | 01/05/2009
1        | painting     | 01/10/2009
2        | preparing    | 02/05/09
2        | painting     | NULL
3        | preparing    | 03/01/2009
3        | scrubbing    | 03/15/2009
3        | painting     | 03/10/2009
4        | bending      | NULL
4        | crashing     | NULL
4        | staining     | NULL
4        | painting     | NULL
```

Desired output (finished orders):

```
order_no
1
3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll could also use **count**, **group by** and **having**. This avoids having to do any table joins which is more efficient.

```
create table #Orders (
    order_no int,
    suboperation varchar(30),
    finished smalldatetime)

insert into #Orders values (1 , 'preparing' , '01/01/2009')
insert into #Orders values (1 , 'scrubbing' , '01/05/2009')
insert into #Orders values (1 , 'painting' , '01/10/2009')
insert into #Orders values (2 , 'preparing' , '02/05/09')
insert into #Orders values (2 , 'painting' , NULL)
insert into #Orders values (3 , 'preparing' , '03/01/2009')
insert into #Orders values (3 , 'scrubbing' , '03/15/2009')
insert into #Orders values (3 , 'painting' , '03/10/2009')
insert into #Orders values (4 , 'bending' , NULL)
insert into #Orders values (4 , 'crashing' , NULL)
insert into #Orders values (4 , 'staining' , NULL)
insert into #Orders values (4 , 'painting' , NULL)

select 
    order_no, 
    count(1) As NoOfSubtasks --count(1) gives the number of rows in the group
    count(finished) As NoFinished, --count will not count nulls
from #Stuff
group by 
     order_no
having 
    count(finished) = count(1) --if finished = number of tasks then it's complete

drop table #Orders
```

Answer (score 1):

A good ol' `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause ought to work here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.order_no
FROM orders o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT p.order_no
                  FROM orders p
                  WHERE p.order_no = o.order_no 
                  AND p.finished IS NULL)
```

Comment: This will repeat the order number. You could fix this by making it SELECT distinct o.order_no

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a way to use the MIN function, and came up with this:

SELECT     order_no

FROM         Orders

GROUP BY order_no

HAVING      (MIN(ISNULL(finished, 0)) <> 0)

null can be annoying...

not as performant, maybe, but easier for me to understand.

Comment: This one look good too but I had to change it for Acccess.
SELECT order_no
FROM Orders
GROUP BY order_no
HAVING (MIN(ISNULL(finished)) = 0);

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT order_no, suboperation, finished
FROM orders o1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
        FROM orders o2 
        WHERE o1.order_no = o2.order_no 
        AND o2 IS NULL )
```

Comment: fix 'AND o2.finished IS NULL'

Also this is returning a row for each of the subtasks.

Comment: IS NULL selects all unclosed orders, that is why this construct framed by NOT EXISTS